# The range of Kendall tau for the Frank copula

Tags: copula

Considering that θ in Frank copula is a function of the Kendall's tau as follows:

[image]

I would like to know the range of Kendall's tau that can be used in the Frank copula.

Thank you in advance for any helps.

Comment: Could any close voter please indicate what's unclear about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\tau = 1+\frac{4}{\theta}[D_1(\theta)-1]$ with $D_1(\theta)= \frac{1}{\theta}\int_0^\theta \frac{t}{e^t-1} dt$,

where is the $D_n(x)$ is the [Debye function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debye_function). This is set as an exercise in Nelsen's book.

As far as I can see, the possible range of population $\tau$ values appears to be $(-1,1)\,\text{\\}\,\{0\}$. That is, between $-1$ and $1$, but not including the endpoints; you get as close to $1$ or $-1$ as you like by choosing sufficiently large parameter values with sign the same as $\tau$, and (strictly speaking) omitting $0$ (though again, you can get as close as you like by choosing the parameter close to $0$; however the independence copula is normally regarded as included).

Comment: Thank you for the response. I would like to know the range of τ as θ ∈ R/0. Can we determine a range for τ explicitly?

Comment: Sorry, I made an edit.

Answer (score 1):

The table at the bottom of this [copula page](http://stanfordphd.com/Copula.html) gives Kendall's tau as a function of $\theta$. In general,

*... Joe, H. (2014). Dependence Modeling with Copulas. Chapman & Hall / CRC.*

contains many formulas and other results on specific copula families.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I would like to know the range of τ as θ ∈ R/0. Can we determine a range for τ explicitly?